# Selecting estimator method for network performance

Tags: machine-learning, kalman-filter

Wireless network parameters latency, PER, bandwidth is impacted by Channel occupancy percentage  , RSSI , client type.

To estimate if per , latency will cross threshold from continuously reported input parameters which estimation model can be used.
Does kalman filter apply here.

I understand kalman filter requires output to be related to input in equation. This is not case here. Here , set of input parameters impact output , there is high degree of correlation but not direct formula to derive output from input. 
Kindly guide.